# Rollover images not displaying in browser

Tags: css, html, image

I've been building a website. I've just been testing it locally, and everything works as it should, but when I tested it online some of the images didn't load.

The images are not only images but css rollover links, and there are 10 of them, all with the same problem.

Here is the CSS code:

```
.art-links{
width:150px;
height:150px;
display:block;
}
.art-links:hover{
background-position:left 150px;
}

#art1{
margin: -300px 0 0 -300px;
background-image:url

('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/70582811/Website/Artwork/Buttons/art1.jpg');
}
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<a href="#art1" onclick="toggle_on('art1_big'); toggle_on('artbg'); toggle_on('back_off'); 
toggle_on('next1'); toggle_on('prev1'); toggle_off('artwork')">
<div class="centre art-links" id="art1">
</div>
</a>
```

That is the code of just one of the images.

The images do not display in Chrome, Firefox or IE. In both Chrome and Firefox the buttons are still there and usable, but the images are not. In IE however there is nothing.

You can see the problem here: http://testerwebby.tumblr.com/ (click artwork top left image, to get to the problem).

Comment: The images are working fine here...

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. See my answer.

Comment: @dillonbrannick have you considered WordPress? http://wordpress.org/

Comment: I'm not sure what the advantage would be, I just host my code on tumblr and point my domain to it, it works just the way it needs to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have no space in your `background-image` property between `url` and `(`. Removing the space and setting:

```
background-image: url('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/70582811/Website/Artwork/Buttons/art2.jpg');
```

Worked fine for me.

Comment: No problem. Glad you found a solution.